# Kendo UI/jQuery redirect after verification

Tags: javascript, jquery, redirect, window.location

I'm coding hybrate mobile app with Telerik product, AppBuilder. But I have the follow problem:

This is my code:

```
$('#search-btn').on("click", function () {
    var barcode = document.getElementById("product-search-id");
    if (barcode.value == 3800048307270) {
        window.location.href = "../views/scan-view.html#activia-light-yogurt-Blueberry";
    }
});
```

But when I select product with barcode 3800048307270 and click Search, **window.location.href** doesn't redirect me to **../views/scan-view.html#activia-light-yogurt-Blueberry**. If I write web url in window.location.href it redirect me. I'm sure that I set the right path.

Comment: Post your HTML as well.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/aupvz2dd/

Comment: Did you try and put an alert inside your `if` and see if that works?

Comment: Yeah and it works. But when I try to redirect to other remote view it doesn't work.